# Mathematica 10.4.0 closes after 'Plot' command on Mac OS X

Tags: warning-messages, mac-os-x

I have a Macbook air (2013) with OS X 10.8.5, and recently I installed Mathematica 10.4.0. The problem is, every time I try to plot something like

```
Plot[x,{x,0,1}]
```

The program closes and does not show anything. What could it be?

Comment: The official websites says mathematica 10 only supports OS X 10.9 and higher

Comment: I am aware of [changes](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/816033) in 10.4 that make me fairly confident and it *will not* work on OS X 10.8.  This is not a case of "supported on 10.9, may or may not work on earlier".  In this case it definitely won't work on earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica 10.4 requires OS X 10.9 or later.

Your options are:

- Upgrade your OS to 10.9, 10.10 or 10.11
- Use Mathematica 10.3.1 or earlier, which works on 10.7.

The system requirements are documented [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/6479).